# A question about the tabbing environment

Tags: tabbing

On page 122 of Gratzer's book *More Math into LaTeX*, he says that

> The tabbing environment has to be typeset with typewriter style font.

And on page 123 of that book, he says that

> You do not really have to use typewriter style font—just beware of the pitfalls.

My question is what can happen if I do not use the typewriter style font to typeset the tabbing environment? What does the *pitfalls* mean?

Comment: Apart from the fact that almost nobody uses the `tabbing` environment anymore, i guess this is just authors humour.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: the whole point of tabbing (which isn't a very useful environment) is to specify alignment points which are not needed if you use a monospace font where everything is aligned naturally. So certainly tabbing if it is used at all is usually not used with a typewriter style font.